# How to apply constant force to a sprite when finger is on a node and cancel the force on release

Tags: ios, objective-c, sprite-kit, uitouch

In my project I want to move `_character` with an `applyForce:` method, I want the force to be constantly applied to the `_character` when my finger is help on `button` but I also don't want the `velocity` to go over a certain amount.

I've tried the following:

```
-(void)touchesBegan:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event{

    UITouch *touch = [touches anyObject];
    CGPoint location = [touch locationInNode:self];
    SKNode *node = [self nodeAtPoint:location];


        if ([node.name isEqualToString:@"moveRightButton"]){

            _held = YES;

            for (SKPhysicsContact* contact in [self.contactQueue copy]){

                [self handleContact:contact];
                [self.contactQueue removeObject:contact];

            }
            while (_held == YES) {
                [_character.physicsBody applyForce:CGVectorMake(1000, 0)];
            }
       }
    }

-(void)touchesEnded:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event{

    UITouch *touch = [touches anyObject];
    CGPoint location = [touch locationInNode:self];
    SKNode *node = [self nodeAtPoint:location];

        if ([node.name isEqualToString:@"moveRightButton"]){

            _held = NO;

        }

}
```

`_held` is an ivar accessible in the whole class.

Now when I run this I have some type of memory leak causing it to use GB's of memory which goes to 7 gb in about 3 minutes (Maybe because i use `CGVectoryMake:` instead of a set CGVector variable which isn't created every time) also when I click on the buttons nothing happens anymore but when I didn't have the while statement it worked fine but i had to continuously press it to get somewhere.

Answer (score 0):

In answer to the question of how to cap an object's velocity:

```
if(mySpriteA.physicsBody.velocity.dx > 50)
    mySpriteA.physicsBody.velocity = CGVectorMake(50, mySpriteA.physicsBody.velocity.dy);
if(mySpriteA.physicsBody.velocity.dx < -50)
    mySpriteA.physicsBody.velocity = CGVectorMake(-50, mySpriteA.physicsBody.velocity.dy);
if(mySpriteA.physicsBody.velocity.dy > 50)
    mySpriteA.physicsBody.velocity = CGVectorMake(mySpriteA.physicsBody.velocity.dx, 50);
if(mySpriteA.physicsBody.velocity.dy < -50)
    mySpriteA.physicsBody.velocity = CGVectorMake(mySpriteA.physicsBody.velocity.dx, -50);
```